# Keras images with no subfolders

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am new to Deep Learning. I have this question: I am trying to train a network with [this data](http://ai.stanford.edu/~jkrause/cars/car_dataset.html). Everything is in one folder and labels are in a different mat file.

I understand that I can read the data with scipy.io. But how can I get train X in one folder? If I use the built in flow_from_directory it shows no images, because every class should have it's own folder.

How can I create X with only one folder? Now it shows `Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes`

There is just a folder with images. All images are in 1 folder. I mean there is no classes folder. With flow_from_directory you should have something like cars/mercedes, cars/bmw, cars/audi, but my data doesn't have subfolders.

So my question is there any other way to create X data?

Comment: Please post your code where you try to load the data and describe your folder architecture in more detail.

Comment: There is just a folder with images. All images are in 1 folder. I mean there is no classes folder.  With flow_from_directory  you should have something like cars/mercedes, cars/bmw, cars/audi, but my data doesn't have subfolders. So my question is there any other way to create X data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set classes to `None` and put all images into one subfolder of your image folder.

For example:

- `flow_from_directory(directory = "/path/to/your/images/", class_mode="None", …)`
- put your images into `/path/to/your/images/data`

Comment: I had to use `class_mode=None` (i.e. No quotes around None)

Answer (score 1):

The [link](http://ai.stanford.edu/~jkrause/cars/car_dataset.html) you posted also shows [a download link](http://ai.stanford.edu/~jkrause/cars/car_devkit.tgz) to "*A devkit, including class labels for training images and bounding boxes for all images*".

You'll find the information there that you need in order to transform your data set into the desired folder structure required for `flow_from_directory()`.

From the `README.md`

```
-cars_meta.mat:
  Contains a cell array of class names, one for each class.

-cars_train_annos.mat:
  Contains the variable 'annotations', which is a struct array of length
  num_images and where each element has the fields:
    bbox_x1: Min x-value of the bounding box, in pixels
    bbox_x2: Max x-value of the bounding box, in pixels
    bbox_y1: Min y-value of the bounding box, in pixels
    bbox_y2: Max y-value of the bounding box, in pixels
    class: Integral id of the class the image belongs to.
    fname: Filename of the image within the folder of images.
```